# How to render HTML Text To Be Placed Inside third party webpage`s div without iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to generate html as well as SVG code based on my Subsciber`s any of the position of on web page (or you can say any of the div).

I want to give some javascript code to be put in side of that page`s div so at that div whole my code place.

I don't want to use iframe because height and width is not defined its automated.

here what i have tried and i am still trying.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>        
        <div>

            <script>

                (function(){
                    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

                    xhr.open("get","request Url of my side",true);
                    xhr.send();

                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){ 
                        if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
                            document.write(xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    };
                }());

            </script>

        </div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

But what happening here is before response came whole page was loaded and `document.write()` erase existing content and place my `responseText` .

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: 3rd party's page not on your server and not under your control?  You can't change that unless they give you permission to and then you would need to do a cross domain request - originating from their server to yours

Comment: I already take  care about CORS. and i am just creating web service. and providing data to subscribers just like facebook flike, google plus index and pinit indexer. confusion is at rendering data to subscribers

Comment: Okay I did solve it myself with the help of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script answering my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its just take me long time to find document.scripts

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div> 
        Here Is The Code
        <div>
        <script>
            (function(t){
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();xhr.open("get","request url",true);xhr.send();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){ if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){ 
                        document.scripts[document.scripts.length-1].parentNode.innerHTML=xhr.responseText;}}
                 }(this));
        </script>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

JQuery solution. You can write similar in pure java, but its a bit harder. Inside `<div id="results"></div>` you will get your response.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: false
})
  .done(function( html ) {
    $( "#results" ).append( html );
  });
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

EDIT: Pure Javascript solution:

Async=true:

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "test.html", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Async=false:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "test.html", false);
xhttp.send();
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: well the problem is that selector can be anything because subscriber page is not under my control. so i want to render my text without specified a selector

Comment: So you can paste javascript, but you cannot affect page in any other way? And it will be <div></div> without id?

Comment: Yes because i client html page is not under my control.

Comment: If you can use jQuery solution - open it in chrome developer tools, find element you want to past in, right click on it -> copy -> copy selector and paste it instead of #results. Should work.

Comment: well code will be genrate from the server and it will be based on request parameter. so there is not any specific code that i want to place. sync request is an option but browser shows its have been deprecated so no longer its will be supported by browser mozilla and chrome both.

Comment: For example comment above would be `$( "#comment-61645739 > td.comment-text > div > span.comment-copy" ).append( html );`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111114/discussion-between-nisarg-desai-and-rav).

Comment: There is no way to paste it anywhere if you dont have any way to refer to element you want to paste :) There need to be sth. You can modify request, for example to access all comments here you'd use `td.comment-text > div > span.comment-copy` - just modify it a bit and try if u can access it.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081689/html-onload-for-non-body-elements